# when using functional bean registration, is there a way to inform Spring that ClassA is responsible for creating an instance of BeanA?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I've switched a portion of a Spring app to use functional bean registrations.  The motivation for the switch is due to requiring multiple instances of some beans under certain conditions.  It also turns out to be much more concise (which won't be at all apparent with the simplistic examples below).

The code used to look like this (simple example):

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigA {
  @Bean
  public BeanA beanA() {
    return new BeanA();
  }
}

@Service
public class Service1 {
  @Autowired BeanA beanA;
  ...
}

@Service
public class Service2 {
  @Autowired BeanA beanA;
  ...
}
```

I've switched the configuration class to look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigA implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {
  @Override
  public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
    context.registerBean("beanA", BeanA.class, () -> new BeanA());
  }
}
```

The issue I'm now encountering is that Spring is complaining about autowired beans not being found.  With the original code, Spring could determine that a BeanA bean was declared via ConfigA and would create that bean before initializing the services.

With the new code, I guess there is no way for Spring to determine where the BeanA bean(s) are being declared, and so it tries to init the services before the BeanA is initialized (which causes the app to not start).

I was hoping that Spring would prioritize @Configuration classes over @Service or @Controller classes, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I could annotate all the services with @DependsOn("configA"), but there are many services that autowire BeanA (some in other code bases), so the @DependsOn option isn't really realistic.

Question: When using functional bean registration, is there a way to inform Spring that ConfigA is responsible for creating an instance of BeanA?

Comment: Did you try @Lazy
[https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html)

Comment: AndrzejSydor, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, annotating the services with `@Lazy` isn't really an option (similar to the `@DependsOn` issue).  There are many services, some of which are out of my domain.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the functional style of bean registration and enable autowiring mechanism in other beans you can do the following:

1. Remove @Configuration annotation from your `ConfigA` class;
2. Create directory named `META-INF` under `main/java/resources` and create a file named `spring.factories` under the newly created directory;
3. Fill the newly created file with the line `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=(package-name-to-configA-class).ConfigA`

Now Spring should be able to successfully autowire bean named `BeanA` where requested.